The unit ball of the quotient space X/E isometric to the orthogonal projection of B(0,1) onto orthogonal of E
In the lecture notes "Geometric Functional Analysis" by Roman Vershynin, it claims Proposition 2.1 in page 7 (Banach spaces and symmetric convex bodies):

Let $X = (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space. Then its unit ball $B_X$ is a symmetric convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $K$ be a symmetric convex body in $\mathbb{R}^n $. Then $K $ is the unit ball of some normed space $X = (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|) $. Indeed, consider the Minkowski functional of $K$ defined for all $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n $ as
$
\|x\|_K = \inf \{ t > 0 : x/t \in K \}.
$
Then $\|\cdot\|_K $ defines a norm on $ \mathbb{R}^n $, and $ K $ is the unit ball of the Banach space $ (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_K) $.

And he says, ``Using Proposition 2.1, one can easily show that subspaces of Banach spaces correspond to sections of convex bodies, and quotient spaces correspond to projections of convex bodies.''
Proposition 2.3 (Subspaces and quotient spaces). Let $ X = (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|) $ be a Banach space, and let $ K = B_X $ denote its unit ball. Consider a subspace $E $ of $X $. Then:

The unit ball of $ E $ is the section $ K \cap E $

The unit ball of the quotient space $X/E$ is isometrically equivalent to the orthogonal projection of $K $ onto $E^\perp $, denoted $ P_{E^\perp}(K) $.


The first point seems obvious without using the previous proposition, it is enough to say that the unit ball of $E$ consists of the elements of $E$) with norm less than 1, and this is evident.
But for the second point, I do not know which mapping to consider to then show that it is an isometry.
